# RubyGem Gosu 0.10.6 Install Error on Windows 10 using 'gem install gosu'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libgosu

I have updated RubyGems to the newest version, I'm running Ruby 2.2.3p173, but when I go into my Powershell and type `gem install gosu` like RubyGems says, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing gosu:
        invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodEr
ror) in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/gosu-0.10.6-x64-mingw32.gem
```

I'm not working Rails, so I don't have a Gemfile to try to install through. I wanted to start playing with the library locally. Any advice to get it to install?

(I haven't been able to try on OSX because I left my laptop at work, and I won't be back in my office for a week, so right now, it's Win10 only for me.)

Comment: I was able to install an older version of Gosu. I used `gem install gosu -v '0.10.5'` which worked perfectly. When using `gem install gosu -v '0.10.6'` which is the latest version, it's still giving the error on install.

Answer (score 0):

I posted in the GitHub bug forum about this, and downloading and manually installing the gem worked.

https://github.com/gosu/gosu/issues/319#issuecomment-193687898